# How to view the header information of a video file AVI or FLV?

Tags: metadata, avi

How do you view and or edit the metadata or header of a video file?

Answer (score 4):

You can use library like like [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net)

Or you can parse media header info.But it would be hard to learn all media formats header structure like [this](http://www.fastgraph.com/help/avi_header_format.html).